# Serialize Dictionary<,> as array in Json.NET

Tags: json.net

How can I make Json.NET serializer to serialize `IDictionary<,>` instance into array of objects with key/value properties? 
By default it serializes the value of Key into JSON object's property name.

Basically I need something like this:

```
[{"key":"some key","value":1},{"key":"another key","value":5}]
```

instead of:

```
{{"some key":1},{"another key":5}}
```

I tried to add `KeyValuePairConverter` to serializer settings but it has no effect. (I found this converter is ignored for type of `IDictionary<>` but I cannot easily change the type of my objects as they are received from other libraries, so changing from `IDictionary<>` to `ICollection<KeyValuePair<>>` is not option for me.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get this converter to work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public class CustomDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) || 
                TypeImplementsGenericInterface(objectType, typeof(IDictionary<,>)));
    }

    private static bool TypeImplementsGenericInterface(Type concreteType, Type interfaceType)
    {
        return concreteType.GetInterfaces()
               .Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interfaceType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();
        IEnumerable keys = (IEnumerable)type.GetProperty("Keys").GetValue(value, null);
        IEnumerable values = (IEnumerable)type.GetProperty("Values").GetValue(value, null);
        IEnumerator valueEnumerator = values.GetEnumerator();

        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (object key in keys)
        {
            valueEnumerator.MoveNext();

            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName("key");
            writer.WriteValue(key);
            writer.WritePropertyName("value");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, valueEnumerator.Current);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is an example of using the converter:

```
IDictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict.Add("some key", 1);
dict.Add("another key", 5);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, new CustomDictionaryConverter());
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

And here is the output of the above:

```
[{"key":"some key","value":1},{"key":"another key","value":5}]
```

Comment: It would be easier (and more complete) to check for the non-generic `System.Collections.IDictionary` instead. The generic interfaces generally extends the non-generic interfaces. Also, your `TypeImplementsGenericInterface()` method could be simplified using `Any()` instead of `Where().FirstOrDefault() != null`.

Comment: While it would be nice, `IDictionary<K,V>` actually does NOT extend the non-generic `IDictionary` interface.  See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx).  However, for the sake of completeness, I've edited my answer to add support for `IDictionary` and incorporated your other suggestion about simplifying the `TypeImplementsGenericInterface()` method.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah right, I forgot about that. Correction, _immutable_ generic interfaces generally extends the corresponding _immutable_ non-generic  interface, unfortunately it doesn't apply here.

Comment: for anyone else finding this useful. if you want to correctly serialise a Dictionary<int,Object> or similar you need replace writer.WriteValue(valueEnumerator.Current); with serializer.Serialize(writer, valueEnumerator.Current) so that the sub object will be correctly serialize

Comment: @ScottG Thanks for the feedback.  Your suggestion will work even for simple types like `int` and `string`, so this is definitely the way to go.  I've edited my answer accordingly.  Thanks!

Comment: How can I convert a complex dictionary that is deep in a data structure? For example I have a UserInfo class and it has a variable `List<Lineup> lineup` and Lineup has a `Dictionary<Vector2Int, int>`. I need to convert UserInfo class

Answer (score 3):

Figured out another way - you can create custom ContractResolver and set it to `JsonSerializerSettings` before (de)serialization. The one below is derived from built-in `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` to convert serialized property names to camel case but it could be derived from `DefaultContractResolver` if you prefer not to modify the names.

```
public class DictionaryFriendlyContractResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType.IsGenericType && objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>))
            return new JsonArrayContract(objectType);
        if (objectType.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>)))
            return new JsonArrayContract(objectType);
        return base.CreateContract(objectType);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var cfg = new JsonSerializerSettings();
cfg.ContractResolver = new DictionaryFriendlyContractResolver();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myModel, cfg);
```

Comment: Though your code works for serialization, it's not able to deserialize. This answer works in both cases http://stackoverflow.com/a/25064637/2528649