# Serialize Dictionary with complex key to JSON using JsonConverter

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I would like to serialize **Dictionary** with complex key to JSON by serializing it as a list of **KeyValuePair** and deserialize it back to dictionary using Json.Net's **JsonConverter**.

I use this Dictionary as a transfer object's property:

```
public class TransferObject
{
    public string property1 {get;set}
    ...
    public Dictionary<Product,int> Products {get;set;}
}
```

At the end I would like to do something like this:

```
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.Serialize(transferObject, new DictionaryConverter())
```

and

```
var transferObject = JsonConvert.Deserialize<TransferObject>(json, DictionaryConverter())
```

How to implement **DictionaryConverter** that will convert **Dictionary** to list of **KeyValuePair**? ( I have tried, but i cannot deserialize it back)
Is it good idea to convert it do list of KVP? Or maybe there is a better way to serialize Dictionary with complex key to JSON?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Bart, what error message are you getting when you deserialize (or what is your result)? You shouldn't need to do anything special to do this.

Comment: Thank you for response. Will post the code soon.

Comment: Here is the converter code: https://pastebin.com/6vRR1y9M

Comment: 1) Can you [edit] your question to include the code in the question?  2) If you are trying to serialize the dictionary as an array, did you see [Serialize dictionary as array (of key value pairs)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12751354/3744182) or [How can I serialize/deserialize a dictionary with custom keys using Json.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24681873/3744182)?  [Not ableTo Serialize Dictionary with Complex key using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24504245/3744182) might also help.