# Getting Collection text while serializing List<string> inside a Dictionary using JsonConvert in C#

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonconvert

So I have the following data structure defined in my program:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<List<string>, int>> myTopDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<List<string>, int>>();

Dictionary<List<string>, int> myInnerDict = new Dictionary<List<string>, int>();

int myIntValue=1;

List<string> myListValue=new List<string>();
myListValue.Add("Example Text 1");
myListValue.Add("Example Text 2");

//Here I add to my inner dictionary
myInnerDict.Add(myListValue, myIntValue);

//And finally adding to top dictionary
myTopDict.Add("My Data Set", myInnerDict);

//Serialize here
string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myTopDict);
```

When I serialize the data structure, I am getting Collection text in the string as shown below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Why I am not able to see my data in the serialized result?

Comment: Keys in Json have to be a string, you are trying to use a `List<string>`. Are you sure you didn't mean `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<string>>>`?

Comment: can't you just use an array instead of a List inside the value?

Comment: @Yitz Will it make any difference? Can you give an example?

Comment: @FelipeEsteves What will that do in this case? Any example you can provide of using arrays over List will give the desired result?

Comment: @RahulSharma what's the expected JSON output here? Can you give an example of what you want the serialized JSON to look like?

Comment: As mentioned by @Yitz, `Dictionary<List<string>, int> myInnerDict` is a dictionary with **complex keys**.  If this is not a typo and you instead meant `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<string>>>`, then Json.NET does not serialize such dictionaries out of the box, so you will need to implement a custom `JsonConverter` or `TypeConverter`.  For details see [Not ableTo Serialize Dictionary with Complex key using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24504245/3744182).  In fact that may be a duplicate.  Does it answer your question?

Comment: If I use @Yitz structure, I get the error that a key with the same value has already been added in the dictionary. The integer value is cannot be the key since it varies as per my program. I am looking into the custom converter as dbc suggested.

Comment: See also [How can I serialize/deserialize a dictionary with custom keys using Json.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24681873).

Comment: @dbc This converter worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27043792/1807452 . Thanks for the assist.

Comment: I'm surprised that a Dictionary whose key type is `List<string>`. What does key equality mean for two different `List<string>` instances? How is a `List<string>` hashed? Maybe I _just works_, but it certainly wouldn't show up in code I wrote (even ignoring the JSON issues)

Comment: @Flydog57 All the 'messy' structure goes to the front-end where it is parsed by Javascript to generate dynamic data on the `View`.

Answer (score -1):

For me the main problem that you have in your code is that you are using inside the dictionary as a key a list of string. That's why it's appering like that when you serialize the json

I don't know the expected Json result that you want. But if the idea is to have a collection of values, so change the Dictionary<string, Dictionary<List, int>> to Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List>>

Then the serialization will work different

Again, I really don't know the expected output or if that code is what you really want.