# How to save and retrieve Dictionary<object, HashSet<string>> in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext

I have a class `ImportResult` with some properties:

```
public class ImportResult
{
    public string Logs { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Person, HashSet<string>> InjuredPeople { get; set; }
}
```

Then in controller I want to save this `InjuredPeople` to the `HttpContext.Session` so I can use it somewhere else in the code:

```
ImportResult imporResults = someService.GetData();
HttpContext.Session.Set("InjuredPeople", importResults.InjuredPeople);
```

This is how I am also trying to get back this value from session in some different method:

```
public static Dictionary<Person, HashSet<string>> GetInjuredPeople()
{
    var content = HttpContext.Session.Get<Dictionary<Person, HashSet<string>>>("InjuredPeople");
    return content == null ? new Dictionary<Device, HashSet<string>>() : content;
}
```

And my `Get` method for session:

```
public static T? Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
{
     var value = session.GetString(key);

     var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };

     return value == null ? default : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value, settings);
}
```

I am getting error at return in `Get<T>` method:

> Could not convert string '..Person' to dictionary key type '..Person'

How can I fix that?

Comment: Json.NET serializes dictionaries as JSON objects with the keys mapped to the property **names**.  That means the key has to be convertible to and from a string, which your `Person` probably is not.   Thus you will need to store your dictionary as an array of key/value pairs rather than an object.  To do that see [Not ableTo Serialize Dictionary with Complex key using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24504245) and [How can I serialize/deserialize a dictionary with custom keys using Json.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24681873).  In fact this looks to be a duplicate, agree?