# Deserialization issue using a custom resolver with IDictionary<Mycustomclass, List<string>>

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization

**Problem:**

I have a class `Foo` containing an `IDictionary<MyCustomClass, List<string>>`.  I am using a custom `ContractResolver` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25064637/10263) so that my dictionary will serialize as an array of objects containing "Key" and "Value" properties.  That part works fine.  However, when I try to deserialize the JSON back into `Foo` using the same resolver, I get an error as shown below.

**Error:**

> Run-time exception (line 46): Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[mycustomclass,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]'
>   because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. `{"name":"value"}`) to
>   deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. `{"name":"value"}`) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.
>
> Path 'Dict2', line 12, position 13.

**Dotnetfiddle:**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/BKaKab

**My code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;



public class mycustomclass
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public List<string> Productlist {get;set;}
    public List<string> SelectedItems{get;set;}
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        mycustomclass omycustomclass = new mycustomclass{name = "Test",Productlist =  new string[]{"Product1","Product2","Product3"}.ToList(), SelectedItems = new string[]{"Item1","Item2","Item3"}.ToList()};
        mycustomclass omycustomclass2 = new mycustomclass{name = "Test",Productlist =  new string[]{"Product4","Product5","Product6"}.ToList(), SelectedItems = new string[]{"Item4","Item5","Item6"}.ToList()};

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foo.Dict.Add("Gee", "Whiz");
        foo.Dict.Add("Fizz", "Bang");

        Dictionary<mycustomclass, List<string>> custom = new Dictionary<mycustomclass, List<string>>();     
        custom.Add(omycustomclass, new string[]{"l1","l2","l3"}.ToList());
        custom.Add(omycustomclass2, new string[]{"l4","l5","l6"}.ToList());
        foo.Dict2 = custom;


        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        settings.ContractResolver = new DictionaryAsArrayResolver();

        // serialize
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.WriteLine();

        // deserialize
        foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json, settings);
        foreach (var kvp in foo.Dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
        }

    }

    class Foo
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> Dict { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<mycustomclass, List<string>> Dict2 { get; set; }
    }
}

class DictionaryAsArrayResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IDictionary) || 
            (i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>))))
        {
            return base.CreateArrayContract(objectType);
        }

        return base.CreateContract(objectType);
    }
}
```

**JSON:**

```
{
  "Dict": [
    {
      "Key": "Gee",
      "Value": "Whiz"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Fizz",
      "Value": "Bang"
    }
  ],
  "Dict2": [
    {
      "Key": {
        "name": "Test",
        "Productlist": [
          "Product1",
          "Product2",
          "Product3"
        ],
        "SelectedItems": [
          "Item1",
          "Item2",
          "Item3"
        ]
      },
      "Value": [
        "l1",
        "l2",
        "l3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": {
        "name": "Test",
        "Productlist": [
          "Product1",
          "Product2",
          "Product3"
        ],
        "SelectedItems": [
          "Item1",
          "Item2",
          "Item3"
        ]
      },
      "Value": [
        "l1",
        "l2",
        "l3"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone help me get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best way, but it solves your problem.
Create a converter

```
internal class MyConverter : CustomCreationConverter<IDictionary<CustomClass, List<String>>>
{
    public override IDictionary<CustomClass, List<String>> Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new Dictionary<CustomClass, List<String>>();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (object) || base.CanConvert(objectType);
    }
}
```

Add it to your settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        ContractResolver = new DictionaryAsArrayResolver(),
        Converters = new JsonConverter[] {new MyConverter()}
    };
```

Enjoy.

[Sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FZok9I)

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way would be to define the creation method by setting JsonArrayContract.OverrideCreator:

```
public class DictionaryAsArrayResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type objectType)
    {
        if (IsDictionary(objectType))
        {
            JsonArrayContract contract = base.CreateArrayContract(objectType);
            contract.OverrideCreator = (args) => CreateInstance(objectType);
            return contract;
        }

        return base.CreateContract(objectType);
    }

    internal static bool IsDictionary(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType.IsGenericType && objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (objectType.GetInterface(typeof(IDictionary<,>).Name) != null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private object CreateInstance(Type objectType)
    {
        Type dictionaryType = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(objectType.GetGenericArguments());
        return Activator.CreateInstance(dictionaryType);
    }
}
```