# Serializing a Complex Type with IDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I Have this type to serialize to JSON:

```
public class JsonReturn<TEntity, TSource>
{
    public ICollection<TEntity> Success { get; set; }
        
    public IDictionary<TEntity, IEnumerable<string>> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

And It works with Success property, but Errors have failed.

I've read in the [Json.Net reference](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Dictionarys) that IDictionaries has its keys serialized using ToString, which results in a NameSpace description...

So, how can I properly serialize the Key and the value of my dictionary?

Comment: Answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751354/json-net-serialize-dictionary-as-array-of-key-value-pairs