# How to create array of key/value pair in c#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

I have an application that is written on top of ASP.NET MVC. In one of my controllers, I need to create an object in C# so when it is converted to JSON using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` the results looks like this

```
[
  {'one': 'Un'},
  {'two': 'Deux'},
  {'three': 'Trois'}
]
```

I tried to use `Dictionary<string, string>` like this

```
var opts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
opts.Add("one", "Un");
opts.Add("two", "Deux");
opts.Add("three", "Trois");

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(opts);
```

However, the above creates the following json

```
{
  'one': 'Un',
  'two': 'Deux',
  'three': 'Trois'
}
```

How can I create the object in a way so that `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` generate the desired output?

Comment: Try an array of KeyValue pairs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json.Net - Serialize Dictionary as Array (of Key Value Pairs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751354/json-net-serialize-dictionary-as-array-of-key-value-pairs)

Comment: @krillgar - it's not quite a duplicate.  In that question the dictionary entry property names are fixed as `"k"` and `"v"` but the question wants the property names to be the dictionary key values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your outer JSON container is an [array](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Lists), so you need to return some sort of non-dictionary collection such as a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` for your root object, like so:

```
var opts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
opts.Add("one", "Un");
opts.Add("two", "Deux");
opts.Add("three", "Trois");

var list = opts.Select(p => new Dictionary<string, string>() { {p.Key, p.Value }});
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JAeLoH).